# Matlab r2013a , I can't use this function to change support package folder

Tags: matlab

I can't use this function to change support package folder (I use MATLAB r2013a) :

```
matlabshared.supportpkg.setSupportPackageRoot(installDir)
```

Matlab give me this errors:

> Undefined variable `matlabshared` or function
>   "matlabshared.supportpkg.checkForUpdate".

Comment: This feature was not introduced until R2016a. Look at the bottom of the [help page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabshared.supportpkg.getsupportpackageroot.html) to see when a function was introduced.

Comment: So how to set root folder of support packages in matlab r2013a ??

Comment: It does not look like you could change the root folder prior to R2016a